# MS Access won't display line breaks of existing data

Tags: microsoft-access, character-encoding, special-characters, microsoft-access-2013

I am creating an MS Access front end for data from somewhere else.

In this case, it's a linked SQL Server table.
The data is actually imported from a shared-hosting LAMP web server.
It's the results of an online quiz from a Wordpress page, from a plugin (wp-pro-quiz).

I'm going crazy because I simply want to view the data in this one column as plain text, but with line breaks.
But Access is ignoring the line breaks in the data.

I'm in a Form because I'm doing other data entry tied to this info.
I've tried it with a Textbox or a Label -- both are ok because I don't want to edit this column itself.
I keep checking with different tools that there are line break characters.

I also have tried editing the data by using a Textbox and pressing Ctrl-Enter.
**This** gives me a line break on the screen.
I swear when I check the data in a text editor the characters are the same as from my table.
Aaargh!

What does Access want to be happy and show my line breaks from the table?

Answer (score 0):

Well, what Access wants for line breaks it can respect is

- **Windows** line breaks
- == CR-LF
- or - since you like Access -  Chr(13)&Chr(10) , or vbCrLf

If you're data is from a unix box, it's very reasonable it is just using the "linefeed" = LF = Chr(10).

You say you're verifying the source data in a text editor that it has crlf.  I'm assuming you're on Windows if you're using Access.
Because crlf is the standard in Windows, we should ask:

Is there any chance you're doing that verification in a way that's causing all line breaks to appear as crlf in that text editor - hiding your source data problem?
If you copy-and-paste you have even more risk of this in some text editors.

'
'
Having all LF line breaks is a really realistic explanation here.
Since you're comfortable looking at special characters, try checking the line endings in your source data with a tool that never alters the data automatically such as xvi32:
http://www.chmaas.handshake.de/delphi/freeware/xvi32/xvi32.htm
'

- If you do find it is only LF for all your line breaks,
- do a string replace for Chr(10) --> Chr(13)&Chr(10)
- wherever makes the most sense for your application.

and Access will show line breaks.

Comment: yes this worked for me: 
`Etext: Replace([text],Chr(10),Chr(13) & Chr(10))` in query field for example.. assuming field `test` has only LF